# Fluent NHibernate QueryOver not returning expected data? (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, where-clause, queryover

I have a class:

```
public class WorkOrderStatusTracking {
  private WorkOrderStatusTracking_ID _id = new WorkOrderStatusTracking_ID();
  public virtual WorkOrderStatusTracking_ID ID {
    get { return _id; }
    set { _id = value; }
  }
  public virtual String WORK_ORDER_NBR { get; set; }
  public virtual String WORK_ORDER_TASK { get; set; }
  public virtual Int32 GEN_ARG { get; set; }
  public virtual String HOLD_CODE { get; set; }
  public virtual String HOLD_RELEASE_DATE { get; set; }
}
```

a composite id:

```
public class WorkOrderStatusTracking_ID {
  public virtual String WORK_ORDER_NBR { get; set; }
  public virtual String WORK_ORDER_TASK { get; set; }
  public virtual Int32  GEN_ARG { get; set; }
  public override bool Equals(object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
      return false;
    }
    var t = obj as WorkOrderStatusTracking_ID;
    if (t == null) {
      return false;
    }
    if (
      (WORK_ORDER_NBR == t.WORK_ORDER_NBR) &&
      (WORK_ORDER_TASK == t.WORK_ORDER_TASK) &&
      (GEN_ARG == t.GEN_ARG)
    ) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  public override int GetHashCode() {
    return String.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}",
      WORK_ORDER_NBR,
      WORK_ORDER_TASK,
      GEN_ARG
    ).GetHashCode();
  }  
}
```

and a class map:

```
public class WorkOrderStatusTracking_ORM : ClassMap<WorkOrderStatusTracking> {
  public WorkOrderStatusTracking_ORM() {
    Table("TIDWOSTR");
    CompositeId(x => x.ID)
      .KeyProperty(x => x.WORK_ORDER_NBR, x => x.Length(8))
      .KeyProperty(x => x.WORK_ORDER_TASK, x => x.Length(2))
      .KeyProperty(x => x.GEN_ARG);
    Map(x => x.WORK_ORDER_NBR).Length(8);
    Map(x => x.WORK_ORDER_TASK).Length(2);
    Map(x => x.GEN_ARG);
    Map(x => x.HOLD_CODE).Length(3);
    Map(x => x.HOLD_RELEASE_DATE).Length(8);
  }
}
```

however, when I run:

```
List<WorkOrderStatusTracking> WorkOrderStatusTrackings = session.QueryOver<WorkOrderStatusTracking>()
  .Where(x => x.WORK_ORDER_NBR == "00322384")
  .List<WorkOrderStatusTracking>().ToList();

foreach (WorkOrderStatusTracking w in WorkOrderStatusTrackings) {
  Console.WriteLine(...);
}
```

I get zero results...

Now I know for a fact entries exist for this where clause and if I .ShowSql() and copy the query to SQL Developer (this is an Oracle Database) it definitely returns rows, furthermore if I remove my .Where() and put in a .Take(10), I get records coming back. Anyone have any ideas? Why would the .Where not work, despite the generated query working in SQL Developer?

log4net results:

```
NHibernate.Cfg.Environment: 2014-06-02 12:11:55,285 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.Environment - NHibernate 3.3.1.4000 (3.3.1.4000)
NHibernate.Cfg.Environment: 2014-06-02 12:11:55,302 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.Environment - hibernate-configuration section not found in application configuration file
NHibernate.Cfg.Environment: 2014-06-02 12:11:55,304 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : lcg
NHibernate.Cfg.Environment: 2014-06-02 12:11:55,307 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.Environment - Using reflection optimizer
NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration: 2014-06-02 12:11:55,554 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration - Mapping XML:
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"><class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" name="Client.WorkOrderStatusTracking, Client, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" table="TIDWOSTR"><composite-id name="ID"><key-property name="WORK_ORDER_NBR" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"><column name="WORK_ORDER_NBR" /></key-property><key-property name="WORK_ORDER_TASK" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"><column name="WORK_ORDER_TASK" /></key-property><key-property name="GEN_ARG" type="System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"><column name="GEN_ARG" /></key-property></composite-id><property name="WORK_ORDER_NBR" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"><column name="WORK_ORDER_NBR" /></property><property name="WORK_ORDER_TASK" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"><column name="WORK_ORDER_TASK" /></property><property name="GEN_ARG" type="System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"><column name="GEN_ARG" /></property><property name="HOLD_CODE" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"><column name="HOLD_CODE" /></property><property name="HOLD_RELEASE_DATE" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"><column name="HOLD_RELEASE_DATE" /></property></class></hibernate-mapping>
NHibernate.Dialect.Dialect: 2014-06-02 12:11:55,677 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Dialect.Dialect - Using dialect: NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle10gDialect
NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.Binder: 2014-06-02 12:11:55,796 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.Binder - Mapping class: Client.WorkOrderStatusTracking -> TIDWOSTR
NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.Binder: 2014-06-02 12:11:55,862 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.Binder - Mapped property: WORK_ORDER_NBR -> WORK_ORDER_NBR, type: String
NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.Binder: 2014-06-02 12:11:55,864 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.Binder - Mapped property: WORK_ORDER_TASK -> WORK_ORDER_TASK, type: String
NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.Binder: 2014-06-02 12:11:55,864 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.Binder - Mapped property: GEN_ARG -> GEN_ARG, type: Int32
NHibernate.Tuple.Component.AbstractComponentTuplizer: 2014-06-02 12:11:55,886 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Tuple.Component.AbstractComponentTuplizer - No custom accessors found for component: Client.WorkOrderStatusTracking_ID, Client, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
NHibernate.Tuple.Component.AbstractComponentTuplizer: 2014-06-02 12:11:55,892 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Tuple.Component.AbstractComponentTuplizer - No custom accessors found for component: Client.WorkOrderStatusTracking_ID, Client, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.Binder: 2014-06-02 12:11:55,917 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.Binder - Mapped property: ID -> WORK_ORDER_NBR,WORK_ORDER_TASK,GEN_ARG, type: component[WORK_ORDER_NBR,WORK_ORDER_TASK,GEN_ARG]
NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.Binder: 2014-06-02 12:11:55,939 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.Binder - Mapped property: WORK_ORDER_NBR -> WORK_ORDER_NBR, type: String
NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.Binder: 2014-06-02 12:11:55,940 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.Binder - Mapped property: WORK_ORDER_TASK -> WORK_ORDER_TASK, type: String
NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.Binder: 2014-06-02 12:11:55,942 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.Binder - Mapped property: GEN_ARG -> GEN_ARG, type: Int32
NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.Binder: 2014-06-02 12:11:55,943 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.Binder - Mapped property: HOLD_CODE -> HOLD_CODE, type: String
NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.Binder: 2014-06-02 12:11:55,944 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Cfg.XmlHbmBinding.Binder - Mapped property: HOLD_RELEASE_DATE -> HOLD_RELEASE_DATE, type: String
NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration: 2014-06-02 12:11:55,954 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration - checking mappings queue
NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration: 2014-06-02 12:11:55,955 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration - processing one-to-many association mappings
NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration: 2014-06-02 12:11:55,956 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration - processing one-to-one association property references
NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration: 2014-06-02 12:11:55,957 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration - processing foreign key constraints
NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration: 2014-06-02 12:11:55,959 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration - processing filters (second pass)
NHibernate.Dialect.Dialect: 2014-06-02 12:11:55,978 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Dialect.Dialect - Using dialect: NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle10gDialect
NHibernate.Dialect.Dialect: 2014-06-02 12:11:55,984 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Dialect.Dialect - Using dialect: NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle10gDialect
NHibernate.Exceptions.SQLExceptionConverterFactory: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,035 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Exceptions.SQLExceptionConverterFactory - Using dialect defined converter
NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,036 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory - Generate SQL with comments: disabled
NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProviderFactory: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,038 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProviderFactory - Initializing connection provider: NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider
NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,039 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider - Configuring ConnectionProvider
NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,043 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory - Transaction factory: NHibernate.Transaction.AdoNetWithDistributedTransactionFactory
NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,044 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory - Optimize cache for minimal puts: False
NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,045 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory - Connection release mode: auto
NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,046 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory - Default batch fetch size: 1
NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,047 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory - echoing all SQL to stdout
NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,047 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory - Statistics: disabled
NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,048 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory - Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,050 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory - Query translator: NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,052 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory - Query language substitutions: {}
NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,054 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory - cache provider: NHibernate.Cache.NoCacheProvider, NHibernate, Version=3.3.1.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4
NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,055 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory - Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,056 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory - Wrap result sets: disabled
NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,058 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory - Batcher factory: NHibernate.AdoNet.NonBatchingBatcherFactory, NHibernate, Version=3.3.1.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4
NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,059 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory - Default entity-mode: Poco
NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,060 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory - Named query checking : enabled
NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,081 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl - building session factory
NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,083 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl - Session factory constructed with filter configurations : {}
NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,084 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl - instantiating session factory with properties: {'use_reflection_optimizer'='True', 'connection.provider'='NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider', 'connection.driver_class'='NHibernate.Driver.OracleClientDriver, NHibernate, Version=3.3.1.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4', 'dialect'='NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle10gDialect, NHibernate, Version=3.3.1.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4', 'hibernate.dialect'='NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle10gDialect, NHibernate, Version=3.3.1.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4', 'show_sql'='true', 'connection.connection_string'='REMOVED'}
NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,087 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider - Obtaining IDbConnection from Driver
NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,537 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider - Closing connection
NHibernate.Tuple.Entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,640 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Tuple.Entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer - No custom accessors found for entity: Client.WorkOrderStatusTracking
NHibernate.Tuple.Entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,644 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Tuple.Entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer - No custom accessors found for entity: Client.WorkOrderStatusTracking
NHibernate.Tuple.Entity.PocoEntityTuplizer: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,658 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Tuple.Entity.PocoEntityTuplizer - Create Instantiator using optimizer for:Client.WorkOrderStatusTracking
NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlSelectBuilder: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,729 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlSelectBuilder - The initial capacity was set too low at: 8 for the SelectSqlBuilder that needed a capacity of: 11 for the table TIDWOSTR workorders_
NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,734 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister - Static SQL for entity: Client.WorkOrderStatusTracking
NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,735 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister -  Version select: SELECT WORK_ORDER_NBR, WORK_ORDER_TASK, GEN_ARG FROM TIDWOSTR WHERE WORK_ORDER_NBR = ? AND WORK_ORDER_TASK = ? AND GEN_ARG = ?
NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,736 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister -  Snapshot select: SELECT workorders_.WORK_ORDER_NBR, workorders_.WORK_ORDER_TASK, workorders_.GEN_ARG, workorders_.WORK_ORDER_NBR as WORK1_0_, workorders_.WORK_ORDER_TASK as WORK2_0_, workorders_.GEN_ARG as GEN3_0_, workorders_.HOLD_CODE as HOLD4_0_, workorders_.HOLD_RELEASE_DATE as HOLD5_0_ FROM TIDWOSTR workorders_ WHERE workorders_.WORK_ORDER_NBR=? and workorders_.WORK_ORDER_TASK=? and workorders_.GEN_ARG=?
NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,738 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister -  Insert 0: INSERT INTO TIDWOSTR (HOLD_CODE, HOLD_RELEASE_DATE, WORK_ORDER_NBR, WORK_ORDER_TASK, GEN_ARG) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,738 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister -  Update 0: UPDATE TIDWOSTR SET WORK_ORDER_NBR = ?, WORK_ORDER_TASK = ?, GEN_ARG = ?, HOLD_CODE = ?, HOLD_RELEASE_DATE = ? WHERE WORK_ORDER_NBR = ? AND WORK_ORDER_TASK = ? AND GEN_ARG = ?
NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,739 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister -  Delete 0: DELETE FROM TIDWOSTR WHERE WORK_ORDER_NBR = ? AND WORK_ORDER_TASK = ? AND GEN_ARG = ?
NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlSelectBuilder: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,770 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlSelectBuilder - The initial capacity was set too low at: 8 for the SelectSqlBuilder that needed a capacity of: 11 for the table TIDWOSTR workorders0_
NHibernate.Loader.Entity.AbstractEntityLoader: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,776 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Entity.AbstractEntityLoader - Static select for entity Client.WorkOrderStatusTracking: SELECT workorders0_.WORK_ORDER_NBR as WORK1_0_0_, workorders0_.WORK_ORDER_TASK as WORK2_0_0_, workorders0_.GEN_ARG as GEN3_0_0_, workorders0_.HOLD_CODE as HOLD4_0_0_, workorders0_.HOLD_RELEASE_DATE as HOLD5_0_0_ FROM TIDWOSTR workorders0_ WHERE workorders0_.WORK_ORDER_NBR=? and workorders0_.WORK_ORDER_TASK=? and workorders0_.GEN_ARG=?
NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlSelectBuilder: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,778 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlSelectBuilder - The initial capacity was set too low at: 8 for the SelectSqlBuilder that needed a capacity of: 11 for the table TIDWOSTR workorders0_
NHibernate.Loader.Entity.AbstractEntityLoader: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,778 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Entity.AbstractEntityLoader - Static select for entity Client.WorkOrderStatusTracking: SELECT workorders0_.WORK_ORDER_NBR as WORK1_0_0_, workorders0_.WORK_ORDER_TASK as WORK2_0_0_, workorders0_.GEN_ARG as GEN3_0_0_, workorders0_.HOLD_CODE as HOLD4_0_0_, workorders0_.HOLD_RELEASE_DATE as HOLD5_0_0_ FROM TIDWOSTR workorders0_ WHERE workorders0_.WORK_ORDER_NBR=? and workorders0_.WORK_ORDER_TASK=? and workorders0_.GEN_ARG=?
NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlSelectBuilder: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,779 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlSelectBuilder - The initial capacity was set too low at: 8 for the SelectSqlBuilder that needed a capacity of: 12 for the table TIDWOSTR workorders0_
NHibernate.Loader.Entity.AbstractEntityLoader: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,780 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Entity.AbstractEntityLoader - Static select for entity Client.WorkOrderStatusTracking: SELECT workorders0_.WORK_ORDER_NBR as WORK1_0_0_, workorders0_.WORK_ORDER_TASK as WORK2_0_0_, workorders0_.GEN_ARG as GEN3_0_0_, workorders0_.HOLD_CODE as HOLD4_0_0_, workorders0_.HOLD_RELEASE_DATE as HOLD5_0_0_ FROM TIDWOSTR workorders0_ WHERE workorders0_.WORK_ORDER_NBR=? and workorders0_.WORK_ORDER_TASK=? and workorders0_.GEN_ARG=? for update
NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlSelectBuilder: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,781 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlSelectBuilder - The initial capacity was set too low at: 8 for the SelectSqlBuilder that needed a capacity of: 12 for the table TIDWOSTR workorders0_
NHibernate.Loader.Entity.AbstractEntityLoader: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,782 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Entity.AbstractEntityLoader - Static select for entity Client.WorkOrderStatusTracking: SELECT workorders0_.WORK_ORDER_NBR as WORK1_0_0_, workorders0_.WORK_ORDER_TASK as WORK2_0_0_, workorders0_.GEN_ARG as GEN3_0_0_, workorders0_.HOLD_CODE as HOLD4_0_0_, workorders0_.HOLD_RELEASE_DATE as HOLD5_0_0_ FROM TIDWOSTR workorders0_ WHERE workorders0_.WORK_ORDER_NBR=? and workorders0_.WORK_ORDER_TASK=? and workorders0_.GEN_ARG=? for update nowait
NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlSelectBuilder: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,783 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlSelectBuilder - The initial capacity was set too low at: 8 for the SelectSqlBuilder that needed a capacity of: 12 for the table TIDWOSTR workorders0_
NHibernate.Loader.Entity.AbstractEntityLoader: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,784 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Entity.AbstractEntityLoader - Static select for entity Client.WorkOrderStatusTracking: SELECT workorders0_.WORK_ORDER_NBR as WORK1_0_0_, workorders0_.WORK_ORDER_TASK as WORK2_0_0_, workorders0_.GEN_ARG as GEN3_0_0_, workorders0_.HOLD_CODE as HOLD4_0_0_, workorders0_.HOLD_RELEASE_DATE as HOLD5_0_0_ FROM TIDWOSTR workorders0_ WHERE workorders0_.WORK_ORDER_NBR=? and workorders0_.WORK_ORDER_TASK=? and workorders0_.GEN_ARG=? for update nowait
NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlSelectBuilder: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,785 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlSelectBuilder - The initial capacity was set too low at: 8 for the SelectSqlBuilder that needed a capacity of: 11 for the table TIDWOSTR workorders0_
NHibernate.Loader.Entity.AbstractEntityLoader: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,786 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Entity.AbstractEntityLoader - Static select for action NHibernate.Engine.CascadingAction+MergeCascadingAction on entity Client.WorkOrderStatusTracking: SELECT workorders0_.WORK_ORDER_NBR as WORK1_0_0_, workorders0_.WORK_ORDER_TASK as WORK2_0_0_, workorders0_.GEN_ARG as GEN3_0_0_, workorders0_.HOLD_CODE as HOLD4_0_0_, workorders0_.HOLD_RELEASE_DATE as HOLD5_0_0_ FROM TIDWOSTR workorders0_ WHERE workorders0_.WORK_ORDER_NBR=? and workorders0_.WORK_ORDER_TASK=? and workorders0_.GEN_ARG=?
NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlSelectBuilder: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,787 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlSelectBuilder - The initial capacity was set too low at: 8 for the SelectSqlBuilder that needed a capacity of: 11 for the table TIDWOSTR workorders0_
NHibernate.Loader.Entity.AbstractEntityLoader: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,787 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Entity.AbstractEntityLoader - Static select for action NHibernate.Engine.CascadingAction+RefreshCascadingAction on entity Client.WorkOrderStatusTracking: SELECT workorders0_.WORK_ORDER_NBR as WORK1_0_0_, workorders0_.WORK_ORDER_TASK as WORK2_0_0_, workorders0_.GEN_ARG as GEN3_0_0_, workorders0_.HOLD_CODE as HOLD4_0_0_, workorders0_.HOLD_RELEASE_DATE as HOLD5_0_0_ FROM TIDWOSTR workorders0_ WHERE workorders0_.WORK_ORDER_NBR=? and workorders0_.WORK_ORDER_TASK=? and workorders0_.GEN_ARG=?
NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,790 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory - initializing class SessionFactoryObjectFactory
NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,791 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory - registered: f105f54666ff41af8b4a14cf8d3713b3(unnamed)
NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,792 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory - no name configured
NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,793 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl - Instantiated session factory
NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,797 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl - Checking 0 named HQL queries
NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,798 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl - Checking 0 named SQL queries
NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,818 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl - [session-id=4e41d21c-975d-44a2-8d39-a7c36268c157] opened session at timestamp: 635373079168, for session factory: [/f105f54666ff41af8b4a14cf8d3713b3]
NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,939 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator - put criteria=WORK_ORDER_NBR = String@-66999783(hash) alias=this0_
NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator: 2014-06-02 12:11:56,954 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator - returning alias=this_ for criteria=WORK_ORDER_NBR = String@-66999783(hash)
SELECT this_.WORK_ORDER_NBR as WORK1_0_0_, this_.WORK_ORDER_TASK as WORK2_0_0_, this_.GEN_ARG as GEN3_0_0_, this_.HOLD_CODE as HOLD4_0_0_, this_.HOLD_RELEASE_DATE as HOLD5_0_0_ FROM TIDWOSTR this_ WHERE this_.WORK_ORDER_NBR = ?
NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher: 2014-06-02 12:11:57,082 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - Opened new IDbCommand, open IDbCommands: 1
NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher: 2014-06-02 12:11:57,084 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - Building an IDbCommand object for the SqlString: SELECT this_.WORK_ORDER_NBR as WORK1_0_0_, this_.WORK_ORDER_TASK as WORK2_0_0_, this_.GEN_ARG as GEN3_0_0_, this_.HOLD_CODE as HOLD4_0_0_, this_.HOLD_RELEASE_DATE as HOLD5_0_0_ FROM TIDWOSTR this_ WHERE this_.WORK_ORDER_NBR = ?
NHibernate.Type.StringType: 2014-06-02 12:11:57,088 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Type.StringType - binding '00322384' to parameter: 0
NHibernate.Loader.Loader: 2014-06-02 12:11:57,097 [9] INFO  NHibernate.Loader.Loader - SELECT this_.WORK_ORDER_NBR as WORK1_0_0_, this_.WORK_ORDER_TASK as WORK2_0_0_, this_.GEN_ARG as GEN3_0_0_, this_.HOLD_CODE as HOLD4_0_0_, this_.HOLD_RELEASE_DATE as HOLD5_0_0_ FROM TIDWOSTR this_ WHERE this_.WORK_ORDER_NBR = :p0
NHibernate.SQL: 2014-06-02 12:11:57,108 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.SQL - SELECT this_.WORK_ORDER_NBR as WORK1_0_0_, this_.WORK_ORDER_TASK as WORK2_0_0_, this_.GEN_ARG as GEN3_0_0_, this_.HOLD_CODE as HOLD4_0_0_, this_.HOLD_RELEASE_DATE as HOLD5_0_0_ FROM TIDWOSTR this_ WHERE this_.WORK_ORDER_NBR = :p0;:p0 = '00322384' [Type: String (8)]
NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider: 2014-06-02 12:11:57,111 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider - Obtaining IDbConnection from Driver
NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher: 2014-06-02 12:11:57,295 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - ExecuteReader took 181 ms
NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher: 2014-06-02 12:11:57,297 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - Opened IDataReader, open IDataReaders: 1
NHibernate.Loader.Loader: 2014-06-02 12:11:57,299 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Loader - processing result set
NHibernate.Loader.Loader: 2014-06-02 12:12:19,606 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Loader - done processing result set (0 rows)
NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher: 2014-06-02 12:12:19,610 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - Closed IDataReader, open IDataReaders :0
NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher: 2014-06-02 12:12:19,611 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - DataReader was closed after 22496 ms
NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher: 2014-06-02 12:12:19,614 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - Closed IDbCommand, open IDbCommands: 0
NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager: 2014-06-02 12:12:19,616 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager - aggressively releasing database connection
NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider: 2014-06-02 12:12:19,616 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider - Closing connection
NHibernate.Loader.Loader: 2014-06-02 12:12:19,619 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Loader - total objects hydrated: 0
NHibernate.Engine.StatefulPersistenceContext: 2014-06-02 12:12:19,620 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Engine.StatefulPersistenceContext - initializing non-lazy collections
NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager: 2014-06-02 12:12:19,624 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager - after autocommit
NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl: 2014-06-02 12:12:19,625 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl - transaction completion
NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager: 2014-06-02 12:12:19,626 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager - aggressively releasing database connection
NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl: 2014-06-02 12:12:19,630 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl - [session-id=4e41d21c-975d-44a2-8d39-a7c36268c157] running ISession.Dispose()
NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl: 2014-06-02 12:12:19,632 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl - [session-id=4e41d21c-975d-44a2-8d39-a7c36268c157] executing real Dispose(True)
NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl: 2014-06-02 12:12:19,634 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl - closing session
NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher: 2014-06-02 12:12:19,635 [9] DEBUG NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher - running BatcherImpl.Dispose(true)
```

Comment: I have also tried .CreateQuery and .CreateCriteria and all attempts have generated the same base queries, and none have returned records. Yet in each case the resultant queries, when copied into SQL Developer do return records.

Comment: What is the actual `SQL` being generated wit the `where` clause? Have you used a profiling tool to see the SQL and if so can you post it here?

Comment: I haven't done any Oracle profiling yet (I actually need to figure out how to, I have more experience with MMSQL than Oracle). But the query NHibernate is spitting out with .ShowSql() is:

SELECT
  this_.WORK_ORDER_NBR as WORK1_3_0_,
  this_.WORK_ORDER_TASK as WORK2_3_0_,
  this_.GEN_ARG as GEN3_3_0_,
  this_.HOLD_CODE as HOLD4_3_0_,
  this_.HOLD_RELEASE_DATE as HOLD5_3_0_
FROM
  TIDWOSTR this_
WHERE
  this_.WORK_ORDER_NBR = :p0;

:p0 = '00322384' [Type: String (8)]

Why does markdown not work in comments, I can't seem use 'code'.

Comment: Okay, I was able to confirm that the literal query listed above (minus the :p0 = '00322384' [Type: String (8)] part) is actually hitting Oracle and getting run, what I don't know yet it whether or not the :p0 parameter is being passed or not. Not sure how to check for that in Oracle yet...

Comment: Download a trial of NHProf http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof OR use *cough* Log4Net

Comment: Too be honest though the query looks fine, but I can't believe this is a bug so something else is not quite right.

Comment: This is very odd, because I have another class with a roughly identical setup (class, id, classmap) using a composite id, calling a very similiar queryover, and it works wihtout issue.

Comment: I have added the results of log4net. Strangely enough, running my app several times (with no code changes), I did get rows back once or twice... this is completely blowing my mind. I tested using System.Data.OracleClient from my app and I definitely get rows back, it's almost like NHibernate is not processing the returned data, I can see it hang for a couple seconds on "DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Loader - processing result set" but then it logs "DEBUG NHibernate.Loader.Loader - done processing result set (0 rows)".

Comment: As I look at it, more and more it seems to point to the IDataReader. I was able to get a log from a session when I got rows back, and the IDataReader ran for a lot longer. The ExecuteReader that happens just before processing the data, is roughly the same in all cases, under 200ms, however when I didn't get rows back the DataReader apparently ran for 22,496ms, but when I did get rows back it ran for 122,041ms.

Comment: Please can you try NHProf? This shows the actual SQL and the returned rows?

Comment: Seems I found a solution, I'm not sure what driver NHibernate uses by default, but I installed Oracle's 32bit ODAC driver, added a reference to Oracle.DataAccess to my project, and updated my Fluently.Configure() line for the OracleClientConfiguration to include .Driver<NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver>() and everything started working flawlessly (and a hell of a lot faster). If you still want me to profile the old setup just to take a look I can. Just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working by setting up NHibernate to use Oracle's .NET provider instead of the default one. In order to do this, I had to do the following:

```
1. Download and unzip/install the appropriate Oracle Data Access Components, in my case the 32bit ODAC for Oracle 11g (ODAC112040Xcopy_32bit.zip).
2. Add a reference to the Oracle.DataAccess.dll found in the .\odp.net20\odp.net\bin\2.x directory.
3. Copy the OraOps11w.dll found in the .\odp.net20\bin directory directly to my projects bin directory.
4. Copy the following DLLs to my projects bin directory (not 100% sure which of these are necessary, I just copied them all)
    .\instantclient_11_2\oci.dll
    .\instantclient_11_2\ocijdbc11.dll
    .\instantclient_11_2\ociw32.dll
    .\instantclient_11_2\orannzsbb11.dll
    .\instantclient_11_2\oraocci11.dll
    .\instantclient_11_2\oraociei11
    .\instantclient_11_2\orasql11
5. Updated my fluent configuration of NHibernate to use the Oracle driver as such:
      Fluently.Configure()
       .Database(OracleClientConfiguration.Oracle10.ConnectionString(OraConStr).Driver<NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver>())
       .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Program>())
       .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Once those changes where made, all table accesses worked, and worked a lot faster. So I'm going to chalk this up to a provider/driver issue. I can only assume that by default NHibernate uses the built-in Microsoft System.Data.OracleClient provider, which has been depreciated for a while.

Though that doesn't explain why when I directly used Microsoft's provider outside of NHibernate, I was able to access the table just fine. I may do further research into this, after I get my project out the door to the clients, because it is a puzzling predicament, and I can't leave a good puzzle unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

Also works for use with .Net 4.0.